# ContainsKey Thread Safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary

In the following code:

```
public class StringCache
{
    private readonly object lockobj = new object();

    private readonly Dictionary<int, string> cache = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public string GetMemberInfo(int key)
    {
        if (cache.ContainsKey(key))
            return cache[key];
        lock (lockobj)
        {
            if (!cache.ContainsKey(key))
                cache[key] = GetString(key);
        }
        return cache[key];
    }

    private static string GetString(int key)
    {
        return "Not Important";
    }
}
```

1) Is ContainsKey thread safe?  IOW, what happens if that method is executing when another thread is adding something to the dictionary?
2) For the first return cache[key], is there any chance that it could return a garbled value?

TIA,

MB

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The inherent thread safety of ContainsKey doesn't matter, since there is no synchronization between ContainsKey & cache[key].

For example:

```
if (cache.ContainsKey(key))
   // Switch to another thread, which deletes the key.
   return cache[key];
```

MSDN is pretty clear on this point:

> To allow the collection to be accessed
>   by multiple threads for reading and
>   writing, you must implement your own
>   synchronization.

For more info, JaredPar posted a great blog entry at http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/02/11/why-are-thread-safe-collections-so-hard.aspx on thread-safe collections.

Answer (score 8):

No, ContainsKey is not thread-safe if you're writing values while you're trying to read.

Yes, there is a chance you could get back invalid results -- but you'll probably start seeing exceptions first.

Take a look at the ReaderWriterLockSlim for locking in situations like this -- it's built to do this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what it says in the [MSDN documentation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> A Dictionary<(Of <(TKey, TValue>)>)
>   can support multiple readers
>   concurrently, as long as the
>   collection is not modified. Even so,
>   enumerating through a collection is
>   intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. In the rare case where an
>   enumeration contends with write
>   accesses, the collection must be
>   locked during the entire enumeration.
>   To allow the collection to be accessed
>   by multiple threads for reading and
>   writing, you must implement your own
>   synchronization.

If I'm reading that correctly, I don't believe that it is thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is not *Thread-Safe*.

If you say that

> what happens if that method is
>   executing when another thread is
>   adding something to the dictionary?

then I suppose other functions access the `cache` as well. You need to synchronize  accesses(reading and writing) to the `cache`. Use your lock object in all of these operations.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its not thread safe,

I would suggest go thru below link, it shows implementation of the thread safe dictionary, or its better to develop your own synchronization.

http://lysaghtn.weebly.com/synchronised-dictionary.html

Comment: Link not found (404).